# Are there any thread restrictions on performing operations on the Here SDK Map object?

Tags: android, here-api

The way I understand the HERE Android SDK is that there's a `MapView` that has a backing `Map` object. Adding objects, setting the center, zooming etc should be performed on the `Map` object and this eventually reflects on the `MapView`.

**Question:**

> Are there any restrictions on what thread the operations on the `Map` object must be performed? For example, must they all be called on the UI thread? Also, should multiple subsequent calls be synchronized?

I ask this because I want to make multiple changes in a Map (resize the map view, change some visible layers, change the scheme, add a MapRoute and zoom out to the bounding box of the route). When I try this, it sometimes works but sometimes doesn't. Sometimes, only some of the operations are applied. For example, everything works except the zoom is not applied.

I know there are some listeners that can help me:

1. `Map.OnTransformListener` - this I can use to let me know when a zooming operation has ended
2. `Map.OnSchemeChangedListener` - this I can use to know when a scheme change event has ended

What is not clear to me from the documentation is what other operations constitute a "transform"? Which of these operations must be performed in a synchronized fashion?

For example, is the following code expected to behave correctly?

```
map.setCenter(coordinate, Animation.BOW, 18, 0f, 60f);
map.addMapObject(routeObject);
map.setVisibleLayers(layersToShow, true);
map.setScheme(Map.Scheme.NORMAL_DAY)
```

Note that in the above example, I'm proceeding to make changes immediately after `setCenter` even before the animation is complete. Is this the expected way to use the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no restriction on what thread you call the API from. Internally, all calls are synchronized and thread safe.

What you are looking for is the MapView#executeSynchronized API. [[link]](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/content/api_reference_java/com/here/android/mpa/mapping/Map.html#executeSynchronized-java.lang.Runnable-) This will batch up a few operations into one screen redraw. [At least when I wrote that API a few years ago]

What you are experiencing happens because the underlying rendering thread started drawing some of the commands from the calling thread. This caused subsequent calls to lose effect.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on `executeSynchronized`. Still doesn't help. I re-ordered my map operations to do `setCenter` last (after everything else). Yet sometimes it doesn't complete the operation. It sets the center but doesn't zoom in to the value I specify. Since `setCenter` is an atomic call, I don't see what else could be the problem. I also tried with `zoomTo` but it did not help.

I'm scroll through a list of locations and everytime one of them is selected, I perform a bunch of map operations. I see the problem when I scroll very quickly (previous operation hasn't completed yet). Any tips?

Comment: Oh, also because you are Animation.BOW. This will cancel all previous operations. Depending on what happens with the rendering thread you will see different results. One way is to set the properties first, then fire a delayed set center ~100ms. A rendering frame should be <30ms.

Comment: Your tips are really insightful. Thanks! I still see the problem though (tried also adding the 100 ms delay). Like you said, if I use `Animation.NONE` then the problem disappears. With `LINEAR` or `BOW` about 30% of the time the zoom operation only completes partially. 

What do you mean by "the render thread"? Is it possible to debug or profile this somehow?

Comment: The SDK is designed much like a standard rendering engine. The app main thread intercepts user events and delegates a set of operations to a background thread. The background thread hosts the opengl context where the map is drawn. There isn't an easy way for an external developer to open the box further as all the code is proprietory.

Comment: One other way to perform your animation is to make your own bezier curve animator. Compute the keypoints and manually move the map frame by frame to make a custom animation.

Comment: Note; I no longer work for HERE, but was the original author of the SDK.